# Concatenation of string and int value in nim

Tags: nim-lang

I want to concatenate string and int. But it doesn't work with & and add operator.

```
echo "abc" & 2
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

There's an operator `$` that converts something to string.

```
echo "abc" & $2
echo "abc", 2 # echo automatically applies `$` to its arguments
```